# Optional JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a parent `device` table, as well as the `division` table.
In between there are the stops and ctrltab tables, each of which have properties device_id that matches with `device`, as as pipe_division_id which connects to the `pipe_division` table.
EDIT: By request I have added sample tables below

Device table

```
device_id | name   | board_number 
--------------------------------
23         Stop1    10
24         Stop2    11
25         Ctrltab1 11
26         Rand_dev 8
```

Stop table

```
device_id | label        | pipe_division_id | length
23          Stop1: Piano   305                16
24          Stop2: Buffet  306                16
```

Ctrltab table

```
device_id | label    | pipe_division_id | ctrl_function
25          Ctrltab1     305              open_window
```

Pipe Division table

```
pipe_division_id | label     | position
305                Lower Box    underneath the stairs
306                Upper Box    above the stairs
307                Side Box     To the left of the console in the closet
```

Expected result of query:

```
name   | board_number | label
Stop1    10             Lower Box
Stop2    11             Upper Box
Ctrltab1 11             Lower Box
```

Essentially, I would like to select all the devices in the `device` table with a board number higher than 10, that have a pipe_division_id that is found by connecting their stop or ctrltab tables.

I tried

```
Select name, board_number, pd.label 
from device d 
JOIN stops s ON s.device_id = d.device_id 
JOIN ctrltab ct ON ct.device_id = d.device_id 
JOIN pipe_division_id pd ON (s.pipe_division_id = pd.pipe_division_id 
                         OR ct.pipe_division_id = pd.pipe_division_id)
```

but this does not bring up any results, I suppose this OR statement is not valid? I would rather avoid a union as the real query is very long and I wouldn't like to repeat all that text just for a minor difference in finding the pipe_division label.

Comment: A few rows of sample data and the expected result would help us greatly to understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.name, d.board_number, COALESCE(pd1.label, pd2.label) AS label
FROM device d
LEFT JOIN stop s ON s.device_id = d.device_id
LEFT JOIN pipe_division pd1 ON s.pipe_division_id = pd1.pipe_division_id
LEFT JOIN ctrltab ct ON ct.device_id = d.device_id
LEFT JOIN pipe_division pd2 ON ct.pipe_division_id = pd2.pipe_division_id
WHERE d.board_number > 10;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5VcjUtx69oQZsfhZwhU2mV/0)

Comment: No explanation needed, because it's here: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) 